# React Native. Show component next to the marker

Tags: google-maps, react-native

Is there a way to create a popup similar to the one shown below .

Im using `react-native-maps`, `google provider` and `markers` which are working well, it is only the popup next to the marker that i am having issues with

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the `Callout` component to do this.

The `Callout` component accepts a custom view and is flexible in what content it accepts:

> Callouts to markers can be completely arbitrary react views, similar to markers. As a result, they can be interacted with like any other view.

Source: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps#custom-callouts

---

So an example fitted to your use case looks something like this:

```
const CustomCalloutView = ({ marker }) => (
  <View>
    <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "row" }}>
      <Text>Kyiv Ukraine</Text>
      <Badge value="2" status="warning" />
    </View>
    <Text>+1°</Text>
  </View>
);

// ...

<Marker coordinate={marker.latlng}>
  <Callout>
    <CustomCalloutView marker={{...marker}} />
  </Callout>
</Marker>
```

For the badge I've used the badge the `react-native-elements` library provides (https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/badge), but you can change this to whatever you want.

---

To make the `CustomCalloutView` content dynamic based on the marker coordinates passed as props you could use the function `reverseGeocodeAsync` from `expo-location` to get info about the location.

Source: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/location/#locationreversegeocodeasynclocation.

Example using dynamic marker coordinates and `expo-location`:

```
import * as Location from "expo-location";
// ...

const CustomCalloutView = ({ marker }) => {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    Location.reverseGeocodeAsync(marker).then(res => {
      setLocation(res[0]);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      {location && (
        <View>
          <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "row" }}>
            <Text>{`${location.city}, ${location.country}`}</Text>
            <Badge value="2" status="warning" />
          </View>
          <Text>+1°</Text>
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};
```